# How can I pass the value from a javascript to php on an html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My use case is to create an HTML form that accepts any international number and pass it to a php app that makes a call to that number via the Twilio API. Now that PHP app requires an HTTP POST request.

I am using the intl-tel-input javascript to format and validate the telephone number entered in the html form. Being new to all this, I wanted to understand how can I take the formatted number from that javascript running on the html form and instantiate a post method from that same html form and invoking the php app.

So far I have only got this, I am not sure how to setup the post method to invoke the php app? Any ideas please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/intlTelInput.css">
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone">
    <button type="submit">Call</button>
</form>

<script src="build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/prism.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/isValidNumber.js"></script>

<script>
var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
window.intlTelInput(input, {
    separateDialCode: true,
    utilsScript: "build/js/utils.js",
}); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the PHP file that initiates the actual phone call:

```
<?php

require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
$from = "xxxxx";
$to = $_POST['phone'];

$call = $twilio->calls
->create($to, $from, array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
print($call->sid);
```

As I mentioned the question is how do I call this php app from the above html form and pass to it the value in the phone variable?

Comment: Just use the JS to validate/update the HTML form field and post as normal?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

First `<button type="submit">Call</button>` => `<button type="button" id="submitButton">Call</button>`

Then add some Javascript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    const button = document.querySelector("#submitButton");
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        sendRequest();
        alert('button clicked');    
    });
}
function sendRequest() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };

  const number = document.querySelector("#phone").value;

  xhttp.open("POST", "/path/to/php/endpoint", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(`number=${number}`);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. Not sure I understand all the function but I hope to learn...

Comment: `window.onload` is there to make sure the eventlistener is set when the DOM is loaded and not earlier. You can remove window.onload if the <script>-Tag has either the `defer`-Attribute set or is included at the bottom of the document.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ajax call with post method :
like this :-
html :

```
<form>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone">
    <button type="button" onclick="return send_number();">Call</button>
</form>
```

jquery :

```
function send_number()
{
    var post_data = { };
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    post_data['phone'] = phone;
    var APPUrl = 'App_receive_number.php'; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: APPUrl,
        data: post_data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(res)
        {
          alert("Success! Sent!"); return true;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Failed! Please Try Again!");
            return false;
        }            
    });
}
```